# Django REST Framework: NestedSerializer in OneToMany relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have 2 related **models**:

```
class Systems(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)

class Teams(models.Model):
    system = models.ForeignKey(Systems, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
```

And 2 **serializers**:

```
class System_serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField

class Meta:
    model = Systems
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Systems.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, system, validated_data):
    system.name = validated_data.get('name', system.name)
    system.description = validated_data.get('description', system.description)

    system.save()
    return system
```

second:

```
class Team_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField
    system_id = System_serializer()

class Meta:
    model = Teams
    fields = ('id', 'system_id', 'name', 'description')

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Teams.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, team, validated_data):
    team.name = validated_data.get('name', team.name)
    team.description = validated_data.get('description', team.description)
    team.system_id = validated_data.get('system_id', team.system_id)

    team.save()
    return team
```

In 'team' entity I just want to have only 'System' ID, not the whole 'System'

How can I use the System_serializer, to serialize 'system_id' in 'team' object?

Thanks!

**ADD**

I tried to use SlugRelatedField:

```
class Team_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.ReadOnlyField
system_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Systems.objects.all(), slug_field='id')

class Meta:
    model = Teams
    fields = ('id', 'system_id', 'name', 'description')
```

But got

```
'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

**ADD2**

Tried to use PrimatyKeyRelatedField:

```
class Team_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.ReadOnlyField
system_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Systems.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Teams
    fields = ('id', 'system_id', 'name', 'description')

def create(self, validated_data):
    return Teams.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

but got on create

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <Systems: Systems object (2)>.
```

Comment: remove `system_id = System_serializer()` from `Team_serializer`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu null value in column "system_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (11, team_name4, team_desc4, null).

Comment: Actually, by default `system` in the team serializer should give you the system_id. If you want to use a different name for the field then you can use the primary key related field of slug related field you have but you need to add the source='system' attribute so it knows where you're getting it from

Comment: @Ken4scholars, OMG! :) All my problems came from wrong naming of key. Thanks U a lot! :)